# telegram botfather doesn't allow making more bots

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make telegram bot .I have made 20 bot so far and now when I select newbot from bot father it says this :
"
That I cannot do.

You come to me asking for more than 20 bots. But you don't ask with respect. You don't offer friendship. You don't even think to call me Botfather"

How Should I make more bots??
Thanks

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it *might* be appropriate to ask on [law.se], but *read their on-topic page first*.

Answer (score 4):

It already said that **you can't** create more bot with this account.

There is no way to do that except delete useless one.

You might want to create bot via your friends' account, it's simplest way.