# Telegram more than 20 bots

Tags: bots, telegram

I have 20 bots in use in Telegram and when I want to create more than 20 the botfather tells me the following:

*That I cannot do.
You come to me asking for more than 20 bots. But you don't ask with respect. You don't offer friendship. You don't even think to call me Botfather.*

In the telegram help I didn't find anything, someone knows something about it.

Thanks, Matías.

Comment: Probably use another number to create more bots?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [telegram botfather doesn't allow making more bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522745/telegram-botfather-doesnt-allow-making-more-bots)

Answer (score 1):

It already said that **you can't** create more bot with this account.

There is no way to do that except delete useless one.

You might want to create bot via your friends' account, it's simplest way.

Please refer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522745/telegram-botfather-doesnt-allow-making-more-bots).